# JointJS - get all successors with links

Tags: javascript, jointjs

To get successors of element I'm using:

```
const successors = graph.getSuccessors(element);
```

But it returns elements without links. Is it some way to specify this function with options `joint.dia.Graph.ExploreOptions` to return also links? Or is it some other way to get successors elements with links together?

Thanks

Rafal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `graph.getSubgraph(cells, [, opt])` method ([documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSubgraph)).

```
var elements = graph.getSuccessors(element).concat(element);
// find all the links between successors and the element
var subgraph = graph.getSubgraph(elements);
// remove the element itself
subgraph.splice(subgraph.indexOf(element), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found solution.

According to [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSuccessors) of `graph.getSuccessors(element [, opt])`

> Return an array of all the successors of `element`.

So I assume that there is no way to get with this function elements and link with this function. I need to get links [separately](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getConnectedLinks) by `getConnectedLinks`. `opt` object can include 3 properties (`inbound` , `outbound`, `deep`) we can play with. For example to get single link with inbound connection it would be:

```
const connectedLinks = graph.getConnectedLinks(task, { inbound: true }); // RETURNS AN ARRAY
```

Best regards,

Rafal